how to handle RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED exception in zeebe
I am using the following library https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/zeebe-client-node-js
I am having issues handling RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED exceptions I tried all the configurations that the library suggests.
I want to achieve the following : try to activate the job 5 times and after that I want to quit
class MyCamunda {
    constructor() {
        this.zbClient = new ZBClient({
            onReady: () => console.log("broker connected")
        })

        this.pollUserTask();

    }

    userTask() {
        this.zbClient.createWorker({
            taskType: 'io.camunda.zeebe:userTask',
            taskHandler: async () => {
                // handle the task
            },
            onReady: () => console.log("worker ready"),
            onConnectionError: () => console.log("worker error")
        })
    }

    async pollUserTask() {
        try {
            const response = await this.zbClient.activateJobs({
                type: 'io.camunda.zeebe:userTask',
                maxJobsToActivate:20,
                timeout: 60 * 1000,
                worker: 'test',
                requestTimeout: 5000
            })

            // handle the task
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error",error)
        } finally {
            setTimeout(() => this.pollUserTask(),5000);
        }
    }

}


I tried to poll the userTasks from the broker but when calling the activateJobs method the application gets stuck it will not resume the execution flow. (seen in the pollUserTask method)
I would expect to get all the userTasks 0..n and I would expect that I would be able to handle the exceptions when they are thrown.
